For Each loop results in "Automation Error = For Loop not Initialized"
I am looking to run all my Outlook rules from one button. I have the following code from another site.
It generates an error:

Run-time error -2146664191 (800c8101)
Automation Error

I have 22 rules but the code will only run the first rule which happens to be named "MKG". If I don't comment out the line On Error Resume Next it will run but then only runs the first rule that is "MKG".
The code falls over at Next with the Automation Error. The For Each rl in myRules seems to be correct but Next will not fire without the Automation Error message.
Sub RunAllInboxRules()
Dim st As Outlook.Store
Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
Dim count As Integer
Dim ruleList As String

On Error Resume Next
    
' get default store (where rules live)
Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore

' get rules
Set myRules = st.GetRules

    ' iterate all the rules
For Each rl In myRules
    ' determine if it's an Inbox rule;
        If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive And rl.IsLocalRule = True Then
     'if so run it
        rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
        count = count + 1
        ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.name
    End If
  Next

' tell the user what you did
ruleList = "These rules were executed against the Inbox: " & vbCrLf & ruleList
MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: RunAllInboxRules"

Set rl = Nothing
Set st = Nothing
Set myRules = Nothing
End Sub


Since posting this question, I placed the same macro on my wife's PC and it runs without error. Both PCs are running Outlook 2019 Desktop under Windows 10Pro. This leads me to believe that my PC has a missing or corrupted file.
My PC runs another Outlook macro without issue.
If I comment it out On Error Resume Next the macro will fall over every time at Next with

Automation error - Loop not initialised

The problem seems to be anything with a loop such as For Each > Next or Do Until or Do While > Loop as even a simple macro with either Next or Loop results in

Automation Error = For Loop not Initialized


st.GetRules() and remove On Error Resume Next

https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-rules-now-using-macro/

Thanks OMR3r but deleting On Error Resume Next makes no difference. If I comment it out the macro will fall over everytime at "NEXT" with "Automation error - Loop not initialised".When I uncomment that line it will run to the end but only processes the first of 22 Rules.

Give a try to execute only active rules with If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive And rl.IsLocalRule = True And rl.Enabled = True Then

Thanks Black Cat. That works but makes no difference to the error. In fact I know the whole is fine because the exact code runs perfectly on my wife's PC without errors. We both run Ofiice 2019 under Windows 10Pro. The seems to be a deeper issue with my PC because for Outlook it won't run even the simplest Macro that includes either ant of  For Each, For, with Next or Do While, Do until with Loop. It errors every time on ether Next or Loop with the error code of "Automation error" -2146664191(800c8101)  For loop not inialized".

What happens if you make a loop one of which generates error in an Excel code? This give hints about the cause if it is a VBA issue or not.

Black cat  - nothing happens as I have multiple macros in Excel that incorporate either For or Do Loops and they all run without error so this is what confuses me with the Outlook error. As I have mentioned in a previous post, I completely uninstalled and re-installed Outlook 2019 in an effort to overcome the error but unfortunately the Automation error persists.

This is not solve your problem but what happens if you move your code in an Excel module set the reference to Outlook and test it there? I checked it in outlook 2010 and run smoothly.

I created a new email profile and added the VBA code.
The problematic macro now runs against two manually created rules. I haven't yet imported all my 22 rules for a complete test.

Until there is a plausible explanation, try indexed loops.
Option Explicit

Sub RunAllInboxRulesIndexedLoop()

    ' base code
    ' https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-outlook-rules-startup/
    
    Dim st As Store
    Dim myRules As Rules
    Dim rl As Rule
    
    Dim count As Long
    Dim ruleList As String
    
    ' get default store (where rules live)
    Set st = Session.defaultStore
    
    ' get rules
    Set myRules = st.GetRules
    
    ' iterate rules with an indexed loop
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To myRules.count
    
        ' determine if it's an Inbox rule
        Set rl = myRules(i)
        Debug.Print "rl.Name: " & rl.Name
        Debug.Print " rl.RuleType: " & rl.RuleType
        
        If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then
        
            Debug.Print " rl.IsLocalRule: " & rl.IsLocalRule
            If rl.IsLocalRule = True Then
                'if so run it
                rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
                count = count + 1
                Debug.Print " count: " & count & " of " & i
                ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
            End If
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    ' tell the user what you did
    ruleList = "These rules were executed against the Inbox: " & vbCrLf & ruleList
    MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: RunAllInboxRules"

End Sub

